# Residue Integration

Tags: residue-calculus

I am attempting to calculate the integral of $\frac{(1+sin(\theta))}{(3+cos(\theta))}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. I have already changed $sin$ and $cos$ into $\frac{1}{2i(z-z^{-1})}$ and $\frac{1}{2(z+z^{-1})}$. I am really stuck now. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Try turning the numerator and denominator in polynomials and then find their zeros.  This should tell you what kind of poles you are dealing with.  From there it's an easy computation of the residues inside the contour.

Comment: Is contour integration the only way you want to do this? There is a direct way.

Comment: I need the contour integration

Comment: @will OK.  I added the contour integral methodology to the direct approach.  Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

If direct way can be considered, just as Dr.MW already answered, tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan \frac \theta 2$ makes the problem simple since $$I=\int\frac{(1+sin(\theta))}{(3+cos(\theta))}d\theta=\int\frac{(t+1)^2}{t^4+3 t^2+2}dt=\int \frac{2 t}{t^2+1} dt+\int\frac{1-2 t}{t^2+2}dt$$ $$I=\log \left(1+t^2\right)+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\log \left(2+t^2\right)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\log\Big(\frac{1+t^2}{2+t^2} \Big)$$ Back to $\theta$ (if required), $$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\log (3+\cos (\theta ))$$ So, since, as explained by  Dr.MW,$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+\sin \theta}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1+\sin \theta}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta
$$ the bounds for $t$ are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, so the logarithmic terms does not contribute and the result is just $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$.

More generally, assuming $a \leq \pi$,$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1+\sin \theta}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta=\sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand is periodic, then

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+\sin \theta}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1+\sin \theta}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{3 + \cos \theta} d\theta
\end{align}$$

where we exploited the fact that $\frac{\sin \theta}{3+\cos \theta}$ is an odd function.

Next, let $u=\tan (\theta /2)$ so that $du = \frac12 \sec^2(\theta /2)$, and $\cos \theta =\frac{1+u^2}{1-u^2}$.  Then, we find the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{3+\cos \theta}$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \arctan (\sqrt{2}\tan (\theta /2)/2) +C$.  Evaluating the anti-derivative between limits of integration reveals

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{3+\cos \theta} d\theta =\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2}$$

---

Now, let's use contour integration.

Let $z=e^{i \theta}$ so that $d\theta=dz/(iz)$.

Next note that

$\frac{1+\sin \theta}{3+\cos \theta}=\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{i(z^2+6z+1)}$.  The only root of the denominator that lies inside the unit circle is at $z=-3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Now the integral of interest is

$$-\int_C \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{z(z^2+6z+1)} dz$$

The integral has two simple poles, one at $0$ and the other at $-3+2\sqrt{2}$.  The evaluation of the integral therefore is, by the Residue Theorem,

$$2\pi i \sum \text{Res} \left(- \left( \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{z(z^2+6z+1)}\right)\right)$$

The residue at $z=0$ is found by evaluating the term $- \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{z^2+6z+1}$ at $z=0$.  We find this first residue to be 1.

The residue at $z=-3+2\sqrt{2}$ is found by evaluating the term $-\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{z(z+3+2\sqrt{2})}$ at $z=-3+2\sqrt{2}$.  We find this second residue to be $-1-i\sqrt{2}/4$.

Putting it all together recovers the aforementioned result!